# How to convert Python project into executable

Tags: python, project, executable, pyinstaller

I have a Python project that I want to convert into an executable. I have installed Pyinstaller. I only know how to convert one single script into .exe, but I have multiple packages with multiple python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The command line I used with success is:

```
pyinstaller --noupx --onefile --add-data="cprofiles.ui;." cprofiles_lmfit.py
```

pyinstaller manages relatively well the multiple '.py' files that you import, no need to cite them. Under the 'add-data' option, you list the non-py files and in my example, the 'cprofiles_lmfit.py' file is the one containing the main.

But as indicated here [need help to compile python with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818993/need-help-to-compile-python-with-pyinstaller) (and in few other posts), I am a beginner with pyinstaller. I was never able to use the 'theano' module and I did not optimize. I still have to test the suggestions in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Converting the main script into .exe should solve the problem, use -onefile to convert it to one exe and rest of the .py files should be included.

Answer (score -1):

1)  Open the command prompt

2)  Install pyinstaller 
    **Pip install pyinstaller**

3)   Test your python script first just to check python script should work with normal 
    .py extension. Saurabh is the name of python file
     **python saurabh.py**

4)  Convert the python into executable file
     **pyinstaller --onefile Saurabh.py**

Notice we have passed “–onefile” as a argument which tell pyinstaller to create only one file

5)   Go to directory and navigate to the dist folder.

Prerequisite : Install PyQt5   to avoid error. 
**pip install PyQt5**

Comment: Question specifies WHOLE PROJECT not ONE SCRIPT. Question also denotes that user knows how to use `--onefile` and is not trying to do that.